# HORM not working on Windows 10 2019 LTSC?

Tags: windows-10, hibernate, uwf

I am trying to enable HORM on my Windows 10 Enterprise 2019 LTSC computer, but it does not seem to be working.

What I am trying to do: I want to have some applications open, and then enable HORM, so that when I first hibernate the device, the hiberfil.sys file will store those open applications. Therefore, every time I resume the computer thereafter (shutdown or restart), it will boot up with those applications already open.

Currently, I am able to enable HORM through the command line as described in the Microsoft Docs just fine. However, after the initial hibernation, if I shutdown or restart the computer, it does not keep any of the apps open. I also have no indication as to whether HORM is actually on, besides the fact that if I try to enable it again, it tells me it is already enabled. Besides that, the boot time is the same and none of the apps remain open.

What I have done so far: I've setup UWF according to the Docs. I have no file or registry exclusions, all volumes are protected, overlay is set to RAM based, and I restarted the device after enabling the UWF filter. Running "uwfmgr get-config" shows this to be true. I've also disabled fast startup, hybrid sleep, and the option to show "Hibernation" in the power options menu.

I've pretty much exhausted all the resources I could find online about this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What version of Windows are you running? "HORM can be used on Unified Extensible Firmware Interface (UEFI) devices running Windows 10, version 1709, or newer versions of Windows, only"

Comment: As David says, HORM needs Windows 10 Enterprise, Windows 10 Education, or Windows IoT Core, version 1709 or newer with UEFI.

Comment: Running 1809, and mine is UEFI device as well.

Comment: Do you have any hidden partitions?

Comment: I have a C partition and an EFI partition. I don't believe either of those are hidden.